# Sorting Excel column by start of word/custom list

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a column

Cat

Bat

Mat

Bat_nk

Mat_po

Cat_rk

I want to sort the top three to match the order of the bottom three. I have many sets within the document, each which needs to be sorted according to its counterpart. How could I go about doing that in a general way, that doesn't involve creating a custom list for each one? Not only sorting by a varying list, but also ignoring anything after/including the underscore?

Thanks in advance, this is driving me nuts. I've searched all over.

Answer (score 0):

I think VLookup and LEFT may help you solve the problem that you facing.

Following is the example i tried:

[image: Custom sort]